# Entity Framework join ошибка

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

Есть две таблицы

```
public partial class Tax
{    
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int category { get; set; }
    public string property { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category1 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Category
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tax> Tax { get; set; }
}
```

Есть метод который должен вывести таблицу Tax join Category, то есть заместо id.Category должен быть title.Category. Запрос выглядит таким образом.

```
    public IEnumerable<Tax> GetAllTax()
    {
        var res = from p in dbentities.Tax
                  join c in dbentities.Category on p.category equals c.id
                  select new { p.name, c.title, p.property, p.price };

        return res.ToList();
    }
```

Но студия ругается на анонимные типы, как лучше преобразовать метод?

> Ошибка    CS0266  Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Collections.Generic.List<>" в "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Нельзя возвращать анонимный тип.**

```
 var res = from p in dbentities.Tax
              join c in dbentities.Category on p.category equals c.id
              select new { p.name, c.title, p.property, p.price }; // ошибка
```

Надо определить какой-то новый модель создать 'Result/Query object'.

```
class TaxQueryModel
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Property { get; set; }
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<TaxQueryModel> GetAllTax()
{
    var res = from p in dbentities.Tax
              join c in dbentities.Category on p.category equals c.id
              select new TaxQueryModel 
                     { 
                      Name = p.name, Title = c.title, Property = p.property, 
                      Price = p.price 
                     };

    return res;
}
```

**можно и так но в дальнейшем это проблема** (и в Entity Framework тоже).

```
public partial class Tax
{    
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int category { get; set; }
    public string property { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; } // добавил
    public virtual Category Category1 { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Tax> GetAllTax()
{
     var res = from p in dbentities.Tax
              join c in dbentities.Category on p.category equals c.id
              select new Tax
              { 
                name = p.name, title = c.title, property = p.property, 
                   price = p.price 
              };

     return res;
}
```

Comment: > Ошибка сервера в приложении '/'.

Элемент модели, переданный в словарь, имеет тип "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebApplication1.Models.TaxQuery]", но для этого словаря требуется элемент модели типа "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[WebApplication1.Models.Agency.Tax]".

Comment: модель не совпадает потому что Где вы вызываете этот код там тоже. надо   поменять этот модель

Comment: @naitosnait Да можно поменять тоже сама модель но дальнейшее это неправильно

Comment: спасибо, заработало

Comment: @naitosnait нет проблем .)

Comment: @naitosnait если ответ вам помог решить проблему, будьте добры, отметье его галкой.